# Inserting non-indented mdframed object in outline

Tags: lists, indentation, enumerate, enumitem, mdframed

I want to be able to put an `mdframed` object inside of an `outline` environment without it being indented to the indentation level that I'm at, and so that I can continue the outline after the `mdframed` like below:

```
    I. text text text
         A. text text text
    __________________________
    |                         |
    |  MD FRAMED STUFF        |
    |                         |
    |                         |
    |_________________________|
         B. text text text
```

Below is the code that I'm trying to use, but I can't get back to level `\2` after level `\0`. I've tried adding the `leftmargin =-1.75cm` and that will move the `mdframed` over, but I have to guess at the amount by which to move it over (ie, -1.75 cm or -1.7cm or ...) and then if I add more to my outline, it is a less than ideal strategy. Please help!

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{outlines}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setenumerate[1]{label=\Roman*.}
\setenumerate[2]{label=\Alph*.}
\setenumerate[3]{label=\arabic*.}
\setenumerate[4]{label=\alph*.}

\usepackage{mdframed}

\title{Notes}
\author{}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{outline}[enumerate]
    \1 text text text 
             \2 text text text 
\0
\begin{mdframed}[frametitle=MD FRAMED STUFF:]
MD FRAMED STUFF
\end{mdframed}
             \2 text text text
\end{outline}

\end{document}
```

At this site, in section 1.4 they seem to be doing something like what I'm interested in, but I don't understand what each part means, and if I could just adjust set those items for the area I want the `mdframed`, and not the entire paper.
http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/outlines/outlines.pdf

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No sledgehammers: the amount of indentation in a list is stored in `\@totalleftmargin`.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[pass,showframe]{geometry} % just for the example

\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{outlines}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setenumerate[1]{label=\Roman*.}
\setenumerate[2]{label=\Alph*.}
\setenumerate[3]{label=\arabic*.}
\setenumerate[4]{label=\alph*.}

\usepackage{mdframed}

\usepackage{color}
\mdfsetup{linecolor=red} % just for the example

\begin{document}

\begin{outline}[enumerate]
    \1 text text text 
             \2 text text text 
\begin{mdframed}[
  frametitle=MD FRAMED STUFF:,
  leftmargin=-\csname @totalleftmargin\endcsname % the devious trick
]
MD FRAMED STUFF
\end{mdframed}
             \2 text text text
\end{outline}

\end{document}
```

Adjust the vertical spacing with `skipabove` and `skipbelow`.

[image]

Comment: This is absolutely wonderful, as I can set it as a default for all the `mdframed` sections in my document. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 3):

LaTeX lists are based on `\parshape`. If you don't mind bashing a sledgehammer through all the latex interfaces you can just zero out the parshape locally:
[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{outlines}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setenumerate[1]{label=\Roman*.}
\setenumerate[2]{label=\Alph*.}
\setenumerate[3]{label=\arabic*.}
\setenumerate[4]{label=\alph*.}

\usepackage{mdframed}

\title{Notes}
\author{}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\makeatletter
\begin{outline}[enumerate]
    \1 text text text 
             \2 text text text 
\par{\parshape0 \linewidth\textwidth
\begin{mdframed}[frametitle=MD FRAMED STUFF:]
MD FRAMED STUFF
\end{mdframed}
\par
}
             \2 text text text
\end{outline}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why, thanks! I don't mind at all :-P Maybe I should?